# Unable to pass result from a function outside of function

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to pass the value outside of function which can be further passed to the python script

This is my javascript code. I want to pass city variable value outside of execute function so that it can be further passed to python script 'word.py' with options variable.

```
function execute(){
   var city = document.getElementById('pass').value;
   return city;   
}
var options = {
scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, 'word/'),
args : [city]
}   
let pyshell = new PythonShell('word.py', options);
pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
alert(message);
 });
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="pass">
<button onclick="execute()" >CLICK</button>    
</body>
```

I am getting  error 'city is not defined'

Comment: You are not doing anything with "city". Call your python function from within the event listener, with the value you need

Comment: Variable scope: you declared `city` inside the function `execute`. You can declare it before: `var city = '';` and use it inside the execute function without redeclaring it with the `var` keyword